# One Variable doesn't have the same Value in my two Processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dmx512

I have a Python script using the multiprocessing and sacn library:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time 
import sacn 

def GettingDMXValues():
    while True:

        receiver = sacn.sACNreceiver(bind_address = "***.**.**.**")
        receiver.start()  

        @receiver.listen_on('universe', universe=1) 
        def callback(packet):  
            #print(packet.dmxData) 
            global DMXValues
            DMXValues = packet.dmxData
            print(DMXValues)
                  
        receiver.join_multicast(1)

        time.sleep(10)  

        receiver.leave_multicast(1)

        receiver.stop()

def printtest2():
    while True:
        print(DMXValues)


p1 = Process(target=GettingDMXValues)
p2 = Process(target=printtest2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    p2.start()
```

For the first function, everything works fine, but when the second function tries to print the `DMXValues` it says they are not defined, even though they have been printed in the other function.

I also can't access the Variable from anywhere else than the callback function

When debugging, depending on where the breakpoint is set, the Variable is either undefined or the Values I am expecting.

If I set the Variable at the start the second function prints the at the start defined Value, while the second one prints the Values I am expecting.

I searched but I did not find anyone with the same problem.

Comment: processes have separate memory space, and cannot share globals

Comment: Right.  The `multiprocessing.queue` can be useful for passing data in between.  It uses TCP sockets to move the data back and forth.

Comment: For the best help, I would recommend you edit you post to be a MCVE. Please reference [the StackOverflow help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for how to make one

Comment: they are *separate processes*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaron's comment about processes not being able to share global variables is your initial problem, but *not* you only problem. You have:

```py
def printtest2():
    while True:
        print(DMXValues)
```

But even assuming you could share variables, (1) `DMXValues` will not be defined until function `callback` assigns a value to this variable and you will most likely get an exception if waiting 1 second to start the `printtest2` process is enough time. And even assuming `callback` creates the variable before `printtest2` runs and you get no exception, you will be in an endless loop printing potentially the same value over and over again until a new value is assigned in `callback`.

Assuming you want to print the value of `DMXValues` once each time a new value is assigned, then you should be using a `multiprocessing.Queue` to which one process will be putting new values and the other process will be getting them for printing:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time 
import sacn 

def GettingDMXValues(queue):
    while True:

        receiver = sacn.sACNreceiver(bind_address = "***.**.**.**")
        receiver.start()  

        @receiver.listen_on('universe', universe=1) 
        def callback(packet):  
            #print(packet.dmxData) 
            global DMXValues
            DMXValues = packet.dmxData
            queue.put(DMXvalues)
                  
        receiver.join_multicast(1)

        time.sleep(10)  

        receiver.leave_multicast(1)

        receiver.stop()

def printtest2(queue):
    while True:
        DNXValues = queue.get()
        print(DMXValues)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue
    p1 = Process(target=GettingDMXValues, args=(queue,))
    p2 = Process(target=printtest2, args=(queue,))
    p1.start()
    #time.sleep(1) # Not necessary
    p2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Each process spawned has it's own separate memory, which can make communicating between them difficult. You probably need to look into using `Manager` from the `multiprocessing` library. Here is a small example script I made to process images, where white pixels were replaced with transparent pixels. Note how when the process is made, it is given the data it has to work with in a JoinableQueue and able to access the same information between the processes via the `new_data` variable that is made as an array handled by `Manager`.

```
from PIL import Image
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue, Manager
from time import time


def worker_function(q, new_data):
    while True:
        # print("Items in queue: {}".format(q.qsize()))
        index, pixel = q.get()
        if pixel[0] > 240 and pixel[1] > 240 and pixel[2] > 240:
            out_pixel = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        else:
            out_pixel = pixel
        new_data[index] = out_pixel
        q.task_done()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time()
    q = JoinableQueue()
    my_image = Image.open('InputImage.jpg')
    my_image = my_image.convert('RGBA')
    datas = list(my_image.getdata())
    manager = Manager()
    new_data = manager.list([(0, 0, 0, 0)]*len(datas))
    print('putting image into queue')
    for count, item in enumerate(datas):
        q.put((count, item))

    print('starting workers')
    for i in range(50):
        p = Process(target=worker_function, args=(q, new_data))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
    print('main thread waiting')
    q.join()
    print("Saving Image")
    my_image.putdata(new_data)
    my_image.save('output.png', "PNG")

    end = time()
    print('{:.3f} seconds elapsed'.format(end - start))
```

It isn't entirely clear how you expect your program to function, so this is the best I can do. I will note that if it's possible for you to work with a `Threading.Thread` object it would probably simplify your code to do that. For example as an exercise I made the same script shown above with Theading as well:

```
from PIL import Image
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time

start = time.time()
q = Queue()

planeIm = Image.open('InputImage.jpg')
planeIm = planeIm.convert('RGBA')
datas = planeIm.getdata()
new_data = [0] * len(datas)

print('putting image into queue')
for count, item in enumerate(datas):
    q.put((count, item))

def worker_function():
    while True:  # Threads will loop forever
        # print("Items in queue: {}".format(q.qsize()))  # If you want to have the progress printed
        index, pixel = q.get()  # grab a item from the stack we are processing
        if pixel[0] > 240 and pixel[1] > 240 and pixel[2] > 240:
            out_pixel = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        else:
            out_pixel = pixel
        new_data[index] = out_pixel  # Process the item by putting the output at the specified index (may fill this array out of order)
        q.task_done()  # Mark this item as completed to remove it from the Queue


print('starting worker threads')
for i in range(100):
    t = Thread(target=worker_function)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
print('main thread waiting')
q.join()  # This will wait for all items in the queue to be marked as complete
print('Queue has been joined')
planeIm.putdata(new_data)
planeIm.save('output.png', "PNG")

end = time.time()

elapsed = end - start
print('{:3.3} seconds elapsed'.format(elapsed))
```

It may not be immediately obvious, but the threaded version is much simpler because it makes it so you don't have to handle the index location of items in the queue, doesn't require a fancy manager array, and also usually runs faster because Processes take a long time to spawn